# Assign new object to variable or not

Tags: java, instance-variables

What is the difference between the codes below?

**Alternative 1:**

```
QuickAction quickAction = new QuickAction();
quickAction.changeFormField();
```

**Alternative 2:**

```
new QuickAction().changeFormField();
```

I think the `Alternative 1` is better if I call only a single method, because it don't use a new memory address to the variable. If I call 2 or more methods, I can create a variable and assign the new object. Is it correct?

Comment: That "memory address" storage is like 4 bytes on a method stack frame. Don't let that be your concern. Use the 2nd option because you're telling other readers the `QuickAction` instance is no longer needed.

Comment: *"I think the Alternative 1 is better if I will call just and just only a method..."* Pretty sure you meant Alternative 2 there.

Comment: Depends if you need `quickAction` later or not. If yes, use 1). If no, use 2). It's a readability question, not an optimization. Let the compiler or the JVM do the optimization for you.

Comment: @Pillar: If the JVM doesn't optimize that away.

Comment: You've tagged your question [tag:instance-variables] but what you've shown is just a local variable, not an instance variable. It makes a big difference to the question.